# Specify Django CMS placeholder type (text,picture,link) in template

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Is it possible to restrict a placeholder type without defining it in `settings.py`?

Something like: `{% placeholder "home_banner_title" image %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. If you look [at the source for the `placeholder` template tag](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py#L254) you will see that only `name`, `width`, `inherit` or `or` are processed.

It wouldn't make sense to do this here anyway as the `placeholder` template tag is rendered during every request and therefore isn't linked to the django admin or to the list of available placeholder types

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported at the moment.